# can't install Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit

I have searched this forum but no-one seems to have my hardware setup. It is relatively new.

I am running 16.04 32 bit happily. However,I would like to run the 64 bit version as I can, theoretically, support this. The DVD based, clean 64 bit install fails at the "Who are you" install page following numerous error messages, screen supplied. My hardware setup is on the second screen shot, but is:
- AMD 9590 8 core cpu (water cooled)
- 16 GB main memory
- Radeon HD 5450 GPU with 2 GB memory
- Gigabyte GA-99-FXA-UD3 motherboard.
- Kingston 60 GB SSD (OS is mounted here)
- WD 1 TB (used to store data)

My machine works perfectly fine with Windows 8, 64 bit version but this OS is not needed. I have tried with a number of burned 64 bit ISO's (16.04.1 and 16.04.2) with the same result.

I would appreciate any feedback.

---

Hardware info from BIOS:

[image: BIOS hardware data]

```
Processor Type     AMD FX(tm)-9590 Eigh
Processor CPUID    600F20h
Processor Speed    4700.00MHz
Processor Clock    200.99MHz
Installed Memory   16384 MB
Model Name         990FXA-UD3
BIOS Version       F2
BIOS Date          07/15/2013
BIOS ID            8A02BG10
LAN MAC Address    74D4359F1B8D
1394 MAC Address   50E5490DA4A8
```

Messages that show up while installing:

```
[    9.596921] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting 0xaa55, got 0xffff
[    9.906074] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   10.166093] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   10.602104] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   10.862117] usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   11.562140] usb 5-3: device not accepting address 4, error -32
[   12.126163] usb 5-3: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[   12.126273] usb usb5-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[   14.802276] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   15.082206] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   30.418916] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   30.698926] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   35.795136] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   36.331158] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   51.411777] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   51.947798] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   62.252221] usb 2-4: device not accepting address 5, error -110
[   63.016251] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
```

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with a USB device. I've had this happen with a particular mouse. Can you try a different kind of mouse if you have one handy?

Comment: mouse works fine under 32 bit version and when accessing BIOS settings. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The installer works fine on the 32-bit version as well, so something must be wrong with the 64-bit version that's not wrong with the 32-bit version. The error messages indicate it's a problem with USB. Either it's that or the install DVD is corrupt somehow and needs to be redownloaded and burned to a new DVD.

Comment: Problem solved! I waffled through other forums and the AMD product support site to verify. It appears that the Gigabyte m/b comes factory set for Microsoft Windows. ie IOMMU is disabled. This is needed by Ubuntu so simply set it to enabled. A little bit of fiddling with the UEFI settings to get the machine to install off the DVD then boot off the 64-bit Ubuntu SSD but all good.